# How to add a comma in between a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a string value such as November 20 2017. How do I add comma in between 20 and 2017. The string value is dynamic.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Search *[python] insert character in string* here (with the brackets), and make an effort to find a solution on your own first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
month, day, year = 'November 20 2017'.split()
result = '{} {}, {}'.format(month, day, year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I actually found the solution to it. 
     "datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('We are in %d %b, %Y')"

Answer (score -2):

```
X = 2017
Y = 12
XS = str(X)
YS = str(Y)
print (XS+','+YS)
```